# How to take a screenshot using Ubuntu server 17 on port 80

Tags: server, apache2, 17.10, webcam, screenshot

I deployed a web page using Apache2 installed on my Ubuntu 17 Azure server.

Is there a command I can run from the terminal where I can capture a screenshot for my website through the port 80?

I tried this command: `gnome-screenshot` but since it is a server it says:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-screenshot:55421): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

How can I add the port number to this command or how can I tell the command to get the screenshot from my web page ?

Comment: *"screenshot"* implies there is something (like a browser) that is rendering the page content

Comment: True, but I do not want to render the page contents. I just want to take an exact screenshot for what is visible to users.

Comment: I mean capture who exactly the page looks and return this picture to the server

Comment: Riiight... but it doesn't "look like" anything until it's been rendered

Comment: Like @steeldriver says, the server serves code, a browser or other UA interprets that to make a page - it looks different according to the browser and the settings in that browser. That said, you can automate the taking of screenshots (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox))and so do it headless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, what you're trying to do is not very well-defined on a headless server. The Apache server does not send any "image" of the webpage (just HTML markup); the image you typically see is generated by your web browser, and the browser can render the same page differently depending on the screen size (and other things like browser version, settings, etc). If you don't have a screen, there is not a clear way to capture an image.

With that being said, one possible solution (likely the easiest one) that I've heard of is **PhantomJS**, a headless web browser: http://phantomjs.org/
I haven't used this method personally though; your mileage may vary.

A more general solution for doing graphical stuff on a server is to create a display for GUI applications to run on using Xvfb. This would allow you to use `gnome-screenshot` like you were trying to. For this, start by installing and running Xvfb:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
export DISPLAY=:0
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1920x1080x24 -shmem -cc 4 &
```

Then install and run Gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-screenshot
gnome-settings &
gnome-panel &
metacity &
```

You'll need a browser. Any will do, but I'll use Firefox for example:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Then run the browser pointed at the webpage you want (in your case, the Apache server on `localhost` port 80):

```
firefox http://localhost &
```

Finally, take the screenshot just like you were trying to:

```
gnome-screenshot
```

Optionally, clean up the processes:

```
killall firefox Xvfb gnome-settings gnome-panel metacity
```

As you can see, this method is much more complicated (and resource-heavy: over 500 MB of installs), but it comes with the advantage that you can take a screenshot of any GUI application just like you would on a desktop, and it isn't limited to just taking screenshots of webpages.

Comment: Thank you so much! That sounds great. Because I do not want to take a screenshot for the HTML tags I want the whole page as it is visible to users. Everything in your solution went well, but when I took a screenshot it says: `** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
[6]+  Done                    firefox http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on this link.
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/how-to-take-screenshot-from-terminal-on.html

or try this on your terminal
gnome-screenshot --help